# Ambiguity in meaning of experiential pseudo-passive and causative

Tags: passive-voice, causative-verbs

Native speakers of English language, What meaning (s) do you infer from the following sentence?

**Bob had his child abducted.**

Does it mean:

1. Bob did experience the abduction of his child.
2. Bob paid someone to abduct his (Bob's) child.
3. Any other meaning?

Comment: Is 'her' in the sample sentence intentional or a mistake?

Comment: Or possibly: Bob paid somebody to abduct another person's child.

Comment: @KillingTime, that was typo.

Comment: @PeterShor that requires the introduction of another person out of this sample sentence. Let's restrict ourselves to just this sentence.

Comment: No, actually, it doesn't.  One can say that Bob's child is actually the kidnapping victim whom he had abducted without detailing the abductor.  But that would not be the natural reading of the sentence.  I would assume it meant 2 unless more data were introduced.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Causative construction](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/403137/causative-construction) // The 'have something done' construction is ambiguous, as pointed out by no less than Chomsky in 1965. 'I had a book stolen' has the senses 'Someone stole a book from me' ('I' am the 'unbeneficiary') **and** 'I got someone to steal a book for me' ('I' am the causative / indirect agent). Pragmatics and especially context usually help disambiguate, but here neither reading sounds very natural. But the causative reading is hopefully contextually the less likely.

Comment: I modified the example sentences to remove some red herrings. Assuming _Bob_ and _his_ are coreferential, it can mean (1) or (2), as Edwin points out. It can also mean anything the speaker or listener think it might mean. That's not really under our control. And if you're going to say sentences like these, there will be many ambiguities.

Comment: It is irreducibly ambiguous unless set in informative context.

Comment: A native speaker would say “Bob’s child was abducted.” No need for this mess.