# Static have or dynamic have in "I had the staff do a thorough search"

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, have, dynamic-verbs

I need to know if "had" is static or dynamic in the following clause.

I had the staff do a thorough search.

I know that if the verb have is marking possession or obligation, some speakers treat it as a static and as an auxiliary in an interrogative clause construction: Had I the staff do a thorough search?

But when "have" is describing an event, it is dynamic and lexical.

So I'm not quite sure if the clause is about an event that happened so the "have" would be dynamic or is the "have" describing possession over the staff that he or she has the staff.

Sorry if this sounds hard to understand but I have a upcoming test and I'm in a hurry.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Does this answer your question, noorav? [Causative construction](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/403137/causative-construction) ("I had the painter paint my house" / "I had my house painted"). I suppose if you have something done, there is a transformation, a perfective aspect, so stasis is ruled out. I'm not sure I'd use 'dynamic' for 'have' here though.

Comment: research does not take a here. Do thorough research [of or on an issue].

Comment: Did I have the staff do thorough research?

Comment: I can't say where you came to "know" those "facts" about _have_, but they're quite incorrect. _Have_ is almost always an auxiliary verb, and then it can be inverted. But it also occurs as a constituent of many constructions: _have your hair cut, have a party, have a baby, have your tires rotated, have your tires slashed, have supper,_ etc, and there it is just another ordinary verb that doesn't invert, doesn't contract, and does require _do_-support. Never mind whether it's active or stative; the constructions can be either.

Comment: Causative "have" can only be dynamic. Btw, causative "have" does not allow passivisation.